# Maximum sum between two leaf nodes

Tags: java, tree

> Given a binary tree in which each node element contains a number. Find
>   the maximum possible sum from one leaf node to another.
>
> The maximum sum path may or may not go through root. For example, in
>   the following binary tree, the maximum sum is 27(3 + 6 + 9 + 0 – 1 +
>   10). Expected time complexity is O(n).
>
> [image: Diagam]

I'm looking for a code review, optimizations and best practices.  I'm also verifying space complexity to be \$O(1)\$.

```
public class MaxSumTwoLeaf {

    private TreeNode root;

    public MaxSumTwoLeaf(List<Integer> items) {
        create(items);
    }

    private void create (List<Integer> items) {
        if (items.size() == 0)  {
            throw new NullPointerException("The input array is null.");
        }

        root = new TreeNode(items.get(0));

        final Queue<TreeNode> queue = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
        queue.add(root);

        final int half = items.size() / 2;

        for (int i = 0; i < half; i++) {
            if (items.get(i) != null) {
                final TreeNode current = queue.poll();
                final int left = 2 * i + 1;
                final int right = 2 * i + 2;

                if (items.get(left) != null) {
                    current.left = new TreeNode(items.get(left));
                    queue.add(current.left);
                }
                if (right < items.size() && items.get(right) != null) {
                    current.right = new TreeNode(items.get(right));
                    queue.add(current.right);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private static class TreeNode {
        private TreeNode left;
        private int item;
        private TreeNode right;

        TreeNode(int item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns the path with max sum between two leaves in the tree.
     * If the tree does not have two leaves then the returned value is arbitrary.
     * 
     * @return  max distance between two nodes in the tree.
     */
    public int maxTwoLeafDistance() {
        if (root == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("The root is not initialized");
        }
        return getMaxDistanceBetweenTwoLeaves (root).maxPathBetweenLeaves;
    }


    private static class NodeData {
        /*
         *       1
         *     /   \ 
         *    2     3
         *    
         * For the node 1, the value of rootToLeafMaxValue will be 4.
         */
        private int rootToLeafMaxValue;
        /*
         *       1
         *     /   \ 
         *    2     3
         *    
         * For the node 1, the value of twoLeavesStatus will be true
         */
        private boolean twoLeavesStatus;

        /*
         *       1
         *     /   \ 
         *    2     3
         *    
         * For the node 1, the value of maxPathBetweenLeaves will be 5
         */
        private int maxPathBetweenLeaves;

        NodeData(int rootToLeafMaxValue, boolean twoLeavesStatus, int maxPathBetweenLeaves) {
            this.rootToLeafMaxValue = rootToLeafMaxValue;
            this.twoLeavesStatus = twoLeavesStatus;
            this.maxPathBetweenLeaves = maxPathBetweenLeaves;
        }
    }


    private NodeData getMaxDistanceBetweenTwoLeaves(TreeNode node) {
        if (node == null) return new NodeData(Integer.MIN_VALUE, false, Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        NodeData leftNodeData = getMaxDistanceBetweenTwoLeaves(node.left);
        NodeData rightNodeData = getMaxDistanceBetweenTwoLeaves(node.right); 

        int treeValue = leftNodeData.rootToLeafMaxValue +  rightNodeData.rootToLeafMaxValue + node.item; // value including the root.
        int max = Math.max(treeValue, Math.max(leftNodeData.maxPathBetweenLeaves, rightNodeData.maxPathBetweenLeaves));

        int maxPathBetweenLeaves = 0;

        /*  
         *       1
         *      / \
         *     2   3
         * 
         * For node 1, leftNodeData.twoLeavesStatus == false and rightNodeData.twoLeavesStatus == false
         */
        if (leftNodeData.twoLeavesStatus == false && rightNodeData.twoLeavesStatus == false) {
            maxPathBetweenLeaves = treeValue; 
        } else 
            /*      1
             *     / \
             *    2   3
             *       / \
             *      4   5
             */
            if (leftNodeData.twoLeavesStatus == false) { 
            maxPathBetweenLeaves = Math.max(treeValue, rightNodeData.maxPathBetweenLeaves);
        } else 
            /*      1
             *     / \
             *    2   3
             *   / \
             *  4   5
             */
            if (rightNodeData.twoLeavesStatus == false) {
            maxPathBetweenLeaves =  Math.max(treeValue, leftNodeData.maxPathBetweenLeaves);
        } else 
            /*        1
             *     /    \
             *    2      3
             *   / \    / \
             *  4   5  6   7
             */
            if (max > treeValue) { 
            maxPathBetweenLeaves = max; 
        } else { 
            maxPathBetweenLeaves = treeValue;
        }

        return new NodeData(Math.max(leftNodeData.rootToLeafMaxValue, rightNodeData.rootToLeafMaxValue) + node.item, node.left != null && node.right != null, maxPathBetweenLeaves);
    }

}


public class MaxSumTwoLeafTest {

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        MaxSumTwoLeaf ms1 = new MaxSumTwoLeaf(Arrays.asList(-15, 5, 6, -8, 1, 3, 6));
        assertEquals(15, ms1.maxTwoLeafDistance());
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        MaxSumTwoLeaf ms2 = new MaxSumTwoLeaf(Arrays.asList(-15, 5, 6, -8, null, null, 6));
        assertEquals(-6, ms2.maxTwoLeafDistance());
    }

    @Test
    public void test3() {
        MaxSumTwoLeaf ms3 = new MaxSumTwoLeaf(Arrays.asList(1, null, 3, null, null, null, 6));
        assertEquals(10, ms3.maxTwoLeafDistance());
    }

    public void test4() {
        MaxSumTwoLeaf ms4 = new MaxSumTwoLeaf(Arrays.asList(-1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7));
        assertEquals(-11, ms4.maxTwoLeafDistance());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Clarity

Minor comment; use [`List.isEmpty()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#isEmpty()) instead of checking for `length() == 0`.

Additionally, the comment itself is wrong; "The input array is null." is not the case. The input array is EMPTY. You should make the exception message reflect that.